# Vuex Action vs Mutations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In Vuex, what is the logic of having both "actions" and "mutations?"

I understand the logic of components not being able to modify state (which seems smart), but having both actions and mutations seems like you are writing one function to trigger another function, to then alter state.

What is the difference between "actions" and "mutations," how do they work together, and moreso, I'm curious why the Vuex developers decided to do it this way?

Comment: See "On To Actions", I think: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#on-to-actions

Comment: related discussion: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/587

Comment: You cannot directly mutate the store's state. The only way to change a store's state is by explicitly committing mutations. For that we need actions to commit mutations.

Comment: @SureshSapkota that statement is very confusing, as both `mutations` and `actions` are definted in the vuex documentation as methods of changing state.  You don't need an action to commit a mutation.

Comment: Mutations, as the name suggests is used to modify/mutate your state object. Actions are quite similar to mutations, but instead of mutating the state, Actions commit mutations. Actions can contain any **arbitrary asynchronous code or business logic**.

Vuex recommends the state object should only be mutated inside the Mutation functions. It is also recommended **not to run any heavy or blocking code inside the Mutation functions since it's synchronous in nature**.

Comment: Because they are copy-pasting the ideas from React now. It was heavily inspired by Angular in the beginning. But now, Vue does whatever react does.

Answer (score 313):

**Question 1**: Why did the Vuejs developers decide to do it this way?

Answer:

1. When your application becomes large, and when there are multiple developers working on this project, you will find that "state management" (especially the "global state") becomes increasingly more complicated.
2. The Vuex way (just like [Redux in react.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux)) offers a new mechanism to manage state, keep state, and "save and trackable" (that means every action which modifies state can be tracked by [debug tool:vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools))

**Question 2**: What's the difference between "action" and "mutation"?

Let's see the official explanation first:

> Mutations:
>
> Vuex mutations are essentially events: each mutation has a name and a
> handler.
>
> ```
> import Vuex from 'vuex'
>
> const store = new Vuex.Store({
>   state: {
>     count: 1
>   },
>   mutations: {
>     INCREMENT (state) {
>       // mutate state
>       state.count++
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```
>
> Actions: Actions are just functions that dispatch mutations.
>
> ```
> // the simplest action
> function increment ({commit}) {
>   commit('INCREMENT')
> }
>
> // a action with additional arguments
> // with ES2015 argument destructuring
> function incrementBy ({ dispatch }, amount) {
>   dispatch('INCREMENT', amount)
> }
> ```

Here is my explanation of the above:

- A **mutation** is the **only way** to modify state
- The **mutation** doesn't care about business logic, it just cares about "state"
- An **action** is business logic
- The **action** can **commit** more than 1 mutation at a time, it just implements the business logic, it doesn't care about data changing (which is managed by mutation)

Comment: The fact that an action "is the business logic" and can dispatch multiple mutations at a time is helpful.  That is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: There is more to it... mutations should basically ONLY change the state as its effect, and nothing more than this; actions may perform not only several dispatchs of mutations, but also other side effects.

For example: you should **never** trigger a notification from inside a mutation, but it is perfectly fine to trigger a notification from an inside an action.

Comment: you cuys are saying you "dispatch a mutation". Isn't the correct wording that you COMMIT a mutation?

Comment: You dispatch actions and commit mutations.

Comment: dispatch is no longer work in vue 2.0 for mutation, you need to commit a mutation in the action.

Comment: @Kaicui This answer is missing a note about mutations always being synchronous, and actions potentially being asynchronous. Other than that, a good answer!

Comment: Simple and precise.

Answer (score 85):

Mutations are synchronous, whereas actions can be asynchronous.

To put it in another way: you don't need actions if your operations are synchronous, otherwise implement them.

Comment: this actually answers a question I was gonna make, about how the todomvc example makes no use of actions.

Comment: _'You don't need actions if your operations are synchronous'_: That is not true: you **do** need actions if you want to compose multiple mutations from the same module, because you can't call another action from an action.

Comment: The obvious follow-up to this answer would be "then why not just have actions and get rid of mutations"

Answer (score 63):

I believe that having an understanding of the motivations behind Mutations and Actions allows one to better judge when to use which and how. It also frees the programmer from the burden of uncertainty in situations where the "rules" become fuzzy. After reasoning a bit about their respective purposes, I came to the conclusion that although there may definitely be wrong ways to use Actions and Mutations, I don't think that there's a canonical approach.

Let's first try to understand why we even go through either Mutations or Actions.

> #### Why go through the boilerplate in the first place? Why not change state directly in components?

Strictly speaking you could change the `state` directly from your components. The `state` is just a JavaScript object and there's nothing magical that will revert changes that you make to it.

```
// Yes, you can!
this.$store.state['products'].push(product)
```

However, by doing this you're scattering your state mutations all over the place. You lose the ability to simply just open a single module housing the state and at a glance see what kind of operations can be applied to it. Having centralized mutations solves this, albeit at the cost of some boilerplate.

```
// so we go from this
this.$store.state['products'].push(product)

// to this
this.$store.commit('addProduct', {product})

...
// and in store
addProduct(state, {product}){
    state.products.push(product)
}
...
```

I think if you replace something short with boilerplate you'll want the boilerplate to also be small. I therefore presume that mutations are meant to be very thin wrappers around native operations on the state, with almost no business logic. In other words, mutations are meant to be mostly used like setters.

Now that you've centralized your mutations you have a better overview of your state changes and since your tooling (vue-devtools) is also aware of that location it makes debugging easier. It's also worth keeping in mind that many Vuex's plugins don't watch the state directly to track changes, they rather rely on mutations for that. "Out of bound" changes to the state are thus invisible to them.

> #### So `mutations`, `actions` what's the difference anyway?

Actions, like mutations, also reside in the store's module and can receive the `state` object. Which implies that they *could* also mutate it directly. So what's the point of having both? If we reason that mutations have to be kept small and simple, it implies that we need an alternative means to house more elaborate business logic. Actions are the means to do this. And since as we have established earlier, vue-devtools and plugins are aware of changes through Mutations, to stay consistent we should keep using Mutations from our actions. Furthermore, since actions are meant to be all encompassing and that the logic they encapsulate may be asynchronous, it makes sense that Actions would also simply made asynchronous from the start.

It's often emphasized that actions can be asynchronous, whereas mutations are typically not. You may decide to see the distinction as an indication that mutations should be used for anything synchronous (and actions for anything asynchronous); however, you'd run into some difficulties if for instance you needed to commit more than one mutations (synchronously), or if you needed to work with a Getter from your mutations, as mutation functions receive neither Getters nor Mutations as arguments...

...which leads to an interesting question.

> #### Why don't Mutations receive Getters?

I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this question, yet. I have seen some explanation by the core team that I found moot at best. If I summarize their usage, Getters are meant to be computed (and often cached) extensions to the state. In other words, they're basically still the state, albeit that requires some upfront computation and they're normally read-only. That's at least how they're encouraged to be used.

Thus, preventing Mutations from directly accessing Getters  means that one of three things is now necessary, if we need to access from the former some functionality offered by the latter: (1) either the state computations provided by the Getter is duplicated somewhere that is accessible to the Mutation (bad smell), or (2) the computed value (or the relevant Getter itself) is passed down as an explicit argument to the Mutation (funky), or (3) the Getter's logic itself is duplicated directly within the Mutation, without the added benefit of caching as provided by the Getter (stench).

The following is an example of (2), which in most scenarios that I have encountered seems the "least bad" option.

```
state:{
    shoppingCart: {
        products: []
    }
},

getters:{
    hasProduct(state){
        return function(product) { ... }
    }
}

actions: {
    addProduct({state, getters, commit, dispatch}, {product}){

        // all kinds of business logic goes here

        // then pull out some computed state
        const hasProduct = getters.hasProduct(product)
        // and pass it to the mutation
        commit('addProduct', {product, hasProduct})
    }
}

mutations: {
    addProduct(state, {product, hasProduct}){ 
        if (hasProduct){
            // mutate the state one way
        } else {
            // mutate the state another way 
        }
    }
}
```

To me, the above seems not only a bit convoluted, but also somewhat "leaky", since some of the code present in the Action is clearly oozing from the Mutation's internal logic.

In my opinion, this is an indication of a compromise. I believe that allowing Mutations to automatically receive Getters presents some challenges. It can be either to the design of Vuex itself, or the tooling (vue-devtools et al), or to maintain some backward compatibility, or some combination of all the stated possibilities.

What I don't believe is that passing Getters to your Mutations yourself is necessarily a sign that you're doing something wrong. I see it as simply "patching" one of the framework's shortcomings.

Comment: For me that's the best answer. Only after reading it, I had this "click" you feel when you feel you understood something.

Comment: Getters are essentially `computed` output.  They are read-only.

A nicer way to view mutations could be to remove the `if else` you have.  The vuex docs say you can house more than 1 `commit` inside an action.  So it would be logical to assume you could commit certain mutation depending upon logic. 

I view actions as a way to dictate WHICH mutation to fire.

Comment: @Tamb : State and Getters both offer contextual data. It makes sense that they would be queried before deciding how to modify the State. When that information can be fetched entirely from the State, it makes sense that the entire logic be encapsulated inside a single Mutation, since it has access to the State. This is standard operating procedure for a setter. What makes less sense is to have a radically different approach simply because we now need to query a Getter for similar information.

Comment: @Tamb: What you're suggesting is that when we need to query Getters we should change the above pattern and move the selection logic to a proxy Action which can access the Getter and can glue together a bunch of tiny dumb Mutations. It does work, but it's still circuitous and does not address the bad smell I'm referring to in my answer, it just moves it somewhere else.

Comment: The docs say that to use getters when you need to compute state.  So it seemed correct to day they are similar to computed properties.  Idk what you're getting at by saying the action can glue together mutations.  The docs clearly say to put business logic inside of the actions.

Comment: @Tamb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method Given 5 different ways of updating the same property based on context, the responsibility usually falls on a single setter to decide how it'll be done. That's not business logic, it's accessor/mutator logic, it belongs in the setter. I'm arguing that if the Mutation doesn't have access to the getter, it has to replicate the exact same getter logic somewhere. This violates the DRY principle, hence bad software smell. Otherwise you have to resort to all sorts of circuitous approaches, as I've explained in my answer, including yours. Bad smell.

Comment: Oh I see now. Good catch

Comment: @MichaelEkoka, you said: "Strictly speaking you could change the state directly from your components. The state is just a JavaScript object and there's nothing magical that will revert changes that you make to it." But, I think this is inaccurate. I believe the "something magical" that happens is related to Vue's change detection. I can reproduce this by changing state directly (not through a mutation) on one component and seeing that it does not get reflected on another component. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 20):

The **main** differences between Actions and Mutations:

1. In mutations you can change the state but not it actions.
2. Inside actions you can run asynchronous code but not in mutations.
3. Inside actions you can access getters, state, mutations (committing them), actions (dispatching them) etc in mutations you can access only the state.

Comment: This was the most important part for me, that you cannot access anything other than a state from a mutation.

Answer (score 17):

I think the TLDR answer is that Mutations are meant to be synchronous/transactional. So if you need to run an Ajax call, or do any other asynchronous code, you need to do that in an Action, and then commit a mutation after, to set the new state.

Comment: This looks like a summarization of the documentation; which there is nothing wrong with.  However, the problem with this answer is that what it asserts isn't necessarily true.  You CAN modify the state inside a mutation when invoking an asynchronous function/AJAX, which can then can be altered in the complete callback. I think this is what's causing so much confusion about why actions *should* be used for best development practices when working with Vuex.  I know that was certainly a source of confusion for me when I started working with Vuex.

Answer (score 17):

I have been using Vuex professionally for about 3 years, and here is what I think I have figured out about the essential differences between actions and mutations, how you can benefit from using them well together, and how you can make your life harder if you don't use it well.

The main goal of Vuex is to offer a new pattern to control the behaviour of your application: Reactivity. The idea is to offload the orchestration of the state of your application to a specialized object: a store. It conveniently supplies methods to connect your components directly to your store data to be used at their own convenience. This allows your components to focus on their job: defining a template, style, and basic component behaviour to present to your user. Meanwhile, the store handles the heavy data load.

That is not the only advantage of this pattern though. The fact that stores are a single source of data for the entirety of your application offers a great potential for re-usability of this data across many components. This isn't the first pattern that attempts to address this issue of cross-component communication, but where it shines is that it forces you to implement a very safe behaviour in your application by basically forbidding your components to modify the state of this shared data, and force it instead to use "public endpoints" to ask for change.

The basic idea is this:

- The store has an internal state, which should never be directly accessed by components (`mapState` is effectively banned)
- The store has mutations, which are synchronous modifications to the internal state. A mutation's only job is to modify the state. They should only be called from an action. They should be named to describe things that happened to the state (`ORDER_CANCELED`, `ORDER_CREATED`). Keep them short and sweet. You can step through them by using the Vue Devtools browser extension (it's great for debugging too!)
- The store also has actions, which should be async or return a promise. They are the actions that your components will call when they want to modify the state of the application. They should be named with business oriented *actions* (verbs, i.e. `cancelOrder`, `createOrder`). This is where you validate and send your requests. Each action may call different commits at different steps if it is required to change the state.
- Finally, the store has getters, which are what you use to expose your state to your components. Expect them to be heavily used across many components as your application expands. Vuex caches getters heavily to avoid useless computation cycles (as long as you don't add parameters to your getter - try not to use parameters) so don't hesitate to use them extensively. Just make sure you give names that describe as closely as possible what state the application currently is in.

That being said, the magic begins when we start designing our application in this manner. For example:

- We have a component that offers a list of orders to the user with the possibility to delete those orders
- The component has mapped a store getter (`deletableOrders`), which is an array of objects with ids
- The component has a button on each row of orders, and its click is mapped to a store action (`deleteOrder`) which passes the order object to it (which, we will remember, comes from the store's list itself)
- The store `deleteOrder` action does the following:

  - it validates the deletion
  - it stores the order to delete temporarily
  - it commits the `ORDER_DELETED` mutation with the order
  - it sends the API call to actually delete the order (yes, AFTER modifying the state!)
  - it waits for the call to end (the state is already updated) and on failure, we call the `ORDER_DELETE_FAILED` mutation with the order we kept earlier.
- The `ORDER_DELETED` mutation will simply remove the given order from the list of deletable orders (which will update the getter)
- The `ORDER_DELETE_FAILED` mutation simply puts it back, and modifies the state to notify of the error (another component, error-notification, would be tracking that state to know when to display itself)

In the end, we have a user experience that is deemed as "reactive". From the perspective of our user, the item has been deleted immediately. Most of the time, we expect our endpoints to just work, so this is perfect. When it fails, we still have some control over how our application will **react**, because we have successfully separated the concern of the state of our front-end application, with the actual data.

You don't always need a store, mind you. If you find that you are writing stores that look like this:

```
export default {
  state: {
    orders: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ORDER (state, order) {
       state.orders.push(order)
    },
    DELETE_ORDER (state, orderToDelete) {
       state.orders = state.orders.filter(order => order.id !== orderToDelete.id)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addOrder ({commit}, order) {
      commit('ADD_ORDER', order)
    },
    deleteOrder ({commit}, order) {
      commit('DELETE_ORDER', order)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    orders: state => state.orders
  }
}
```

To me it seems you are only using the store as a data store, and are perhaps missing out on the reactivity aspect of it, by not letting it also take control of variables that your application reacts to. Basically, you can and should probably offload some lines of code written in your components to your stores.

Comment: ORDER_CANCELED vs cancelOrder explanation finally get me in, thx!

Answer (score 7):

According to the [`docs`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html)

**Actions** are similar to **mutations**, the differences being that:

- Instead of *mutating* the state, **actions** *commit* mutations.
- **Actions** can contain arbitrary *asynchronous* operations.

Consider the following snippet.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++               //Mutating the state. Must be synchronous
    }
  },
  actions: {
    increment (context) {
      context.commit('increment') //Committing the mutations. Can be asynchronous.
    }
  }
})
```

> Action handlers(**increment**) receive a context object which exposes the same set of
>   methods/properties on the store instance, so you can call
>   context.commit to commit a mutation, or access the state and getters
>   via context.state and context.getters

Comment: is posible call from 'mutation' function, a method from vuejs component?

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña I have the same question, because when I try doing that, it throws an error that the local mutation is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

**Mutations:**

```
Can update the state. (Having the Authorization to change the state).
```

**Actions:**

```
Actions are used to tell "which mutation should be triggered"
```

In Redux Way

> ```
> Mutations are Reducers
> Actions are Actions
> ```

**Why Both ??**

When the application growing , coding and lines will be increasing , That time you have to handle the logic in Actions not in the mutations because mutations are the only authority to change the state, it should be clean as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer - I've only just started using vuejs so this is just me extrapolating the design intent.

Time machine debugging uses snapshots of the state, and shows a timeline of actions and mutations. In theory we could have had just `actions` alongside a recording of state setters and getters to synchronously describe mutation. But then:

- We would have impure inputs (async results) which caused the setters and getters. This would be hard to follow logically and different async setters and getters may surprisingly interact. That can still happen with `mutations` transactions but then we can say the transaction needs to be improved as opposed to it being a race condition in the actions. Anonymous mutations inside an action could more easily resurface these kinds of bugs because async programming is fragile and difficult.
- The transaction log would be hard to read because there would be no name for the state changes. It would be much more code-like and less English, missing the logical groupings of mutations.
- It might be trickier and less performant to instrument recording any mutation on a data object, as opposed to now where there are synchronously defined diff points - before and after mutation function call. I'm not sure how big of a problem that is.

Compare the following transaction log with named mutations.

```
Action: FetchNewsStories
Mutation: SetFetchingNewsStories
Action: FetchNewsStories [continuation]
Mutation: DoneFetchingNewsStories([...])
```

With a transaction log that has no named mutations:

```
Action: FetchNewsStories
Mutation: state.isFetching = true;
Action: FetchNewsStories [continuation]
Mutation: state.isFetching = false;
Mutation: state.listOfStories = [...]
```

I hope you can extrapolate from that example the potential added complexity in async and anonymous mutation inside actions.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

> Now imagine we are debugging the app and looking at the devtool's mutation logs. For every mutation logged, the devtool will need to capture a "before" and "after" snapshots of the state. However, the asynchronous callback inside the example mutation above makes that impossible: the callback is not called yet when the mutation is committed, and there's no way for the devtool to know when the callback will actually be called - any state mutation performed in the callback is essentially un-trackable!

Answer (score 2):

This confused me too so I made a simple demo.

**component.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h6>Logging with Action vs Mutation</h6>
        <p>{{count}}</p>
        <p>
            <button @click="mutateCountWithAsyncDelay()">Mutate Count directly with delay</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button @click="updateCountViaAsyncAction()">Update Count via action, but with delay</button>
        </p>
        <p>Note that when the mutation handles the asynchronous action, the "log" in console is broken.</p>
        <p>When mutations are separated to only update data while the action handles the asynchronous business
            logic, the log works the log works</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

        export default {
                name: 'app',

                methods: {

                        //WRONG
                        mutateCountWithAsyncDelay(){
                                this.$store.commit('mutateCountWithAsyncDelay');
                        },

                        //RIGHT
                        updateCountViaAsyncAction(){
                                this.$store.dispatch('updateCountAsync')
                        }
                },

                computed: {
                        count: function(){
                                return this.$store.state.count;
                        },
                }

        }
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import 'es6-promise/auto'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const myStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0,
    },
    mutations: {

        //The WRONG way
        mutateCountWithAsyncDelay (state) {
            var log1;
            var log2;

            //Capture Before Value
            log1 = state.count;

            //Simulate delay from a fetch or something
            setTimeout(() => {
                state.count++
            }, 1000);

            //Capture After Value
            log2 = state.count;

            //Async in mutation screws up the log
            console.log(`Starting Count: ${log1}`); //NRHG
            console.log(`Ending Count: ${log2}`); //NRHG
        },

        //The RIGHT way
        mutateCount (state) {
            var log1;
            var log2;

            //Capture Before Value
            log1 = state.count;

            //Mutation does nothing but update data
            state.count++;

            //Capture After Value
            log2 = state.count;

            //Changes logged correctly
            console.log(`Starting Count: ${log1}`); //NRHG
            console.log(`Ending Count: ${log2}`); //NRHG
        }
    },

    actions: {

        //This action performs its async work then commits the RIGHT mutation
        updateCountAsync(context){
            setTimeout(() => {
                context.commit('mutateCount');
            }, 1000);
        }
    },
});

export default myStore;
```

After researching this, the conclusion I came to is that mutations are a convention focused only on changing data to better separate concerns and improve logging before and after the updated data. Whereas actions are a layer of abstraction that handles the higher level logic and then calls the mutations appropriately

Answer (score 0):

1.From [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html):

> Actions are similar to mutations, the differences being that:

> - Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.
> - Actions can contain arbitrary asynchronous operations.

The Actions can contain asynchronous operations, but the mutation can not.

2.We invoke the mutation, we can change the state directly. and we also can in the action to change states by like this:

```
actions: {
  increment (store) {
    // do whatever ... then change the state
    store.commit('MUTATION_NAME')
  }
}
```

the Actions is designed for handle more other things, we can do many things in there(we can use asynchronous operations) then change state by dispatch mutation there.

Answer (score 0):

Because there’s no state without mutations! When commited — a piece of logic, that changes the state in a foreseeable manner, is executed. Mutations are the only way to set or change the state (so there’s no direct changes!), and furthermore — they must be synchronous. This solution drives a very important functionality: mutations are logging into devtools. And that provides you with a great readability and predictability!

One more thing — actions. As it’s been said — actions commit mutations. So they do not change the store, and there’s no need for these to be synchronous. But, they can manage an extra piece of asynchronous logic!

Answer (score 0):

It might seem unnecessary to have an extra layer of `actions` just to call the `mutations`, for example:

```
const actions = {
  logout: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("setToken", null);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setToken: (state, token) => {
    state.token = token;
  }
};
```

So if calling `actions` calls `logout`, why not call the mutation itself?

The entire idea of an action is to call multiple mutations from inside one action or make an Ajax request or any kind of asynchronous logic you can imagine.

We might eventually have actions that make multiple network requests and eventually call many different mutations.

So we try to stuff as much complexity from our `Vuex.Store()` as possible in our `actions` and this leaves our `mutations`, `state` and `getters` cleaner and straightforward and falls in line with the kind of modularity that makes libraries like Vue and React popular.