# vuex why no async in mutations (seems to work anyways)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I was wondering why all tutorials say that mutations cannot use async code.

I tried it and it obviously works:

```
mutations: {
    clearTodo(state) { setTimeout(() => state.todo = '', 1000) }
},
```

results in the same behaviour as:

```
mutations: {
    clearTodo(state) { state.todo = '' }
},
actions: {
    clearTodoAction({commit}) { setTimeout(() => commit('clearTodo'), 1000)}
}
```

Comment: This pattern insures predictability of changes in your state. Otherwise async calls can rewrite each others results in unpredictable order.

Comment: You can have a look here(https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/42) where Evan You answers why mutations should be synchronous and action asynchronous

Answer (score 3):

Please read the explanation on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299042/vuex-action-vs-mutations-edited-said-vuejs)

to make story short, [this is the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39303713/2631086) in my opinion

[image]