# Vuex mutation not working synchronously but neither returning a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My vuex mutation seems to not work synchronous. It looks like this:

```
mutations: {
    computeStatusData(state, status) {
        if (status.active !== true) { return }

        const started = new Date(status.startedAt);
        started.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const today = new Date();

        status.currentDay = Math.floor((today.getTime() - started.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        status.currentWeek = Math.floor(status.currentDay / 7);

        if (!status.programm.sections) { console.log('No Sections'); return; }

        for (let i = 0; i < status.programm.sections.length; i++) {
            if (status.currentWeek <= status.programm.sections[i].to) {
                status.currentSection = i;
                console.log('Current Section', status.currentSection)
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log('new status!', status)
    },
```

In a method of my component I call it like this:

```
    async loadSections() {

        await somethingElse();

        if (this.status && this.programm.sections) {
            console.log('Recomputing Status')
            this.status.progamm = this.programm;
            this.$store.commit('computeStatusData', status);
            console.log('updated Status', this.status)
        }

        this.$nextTick(() => { this.$forceUpdate(); }) 
    },
```

My console log looks like this:

```
Recomputing Status
updated Status {…}
Current Section 0
new status! {…}
```

If the mutation was synchronous it should log `Current Section 0` and `new Status!` before `updated Status` but it doesn't.

It doesnt seem to return a Promise because when I do `console.log(this.$store.commit('computeStatusData', status));` it just logs `undefined`.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the commit doesn't log (e.g. status is not active). And what you see is another run of the mutation from another place after loadSections() is over?
I'd put a log at the beginning of the mutation code just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of mutate a status is inside an action.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

A helpful question:
[Vuex Action vs Mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299042/vuex-action-vs-mutations)

Comment: I tried using the same code in a vuex action which is intented  to be  called from outside the store as far as I know but I get the same behavior,

Comment: It doesn't answer the question @Eduardo . Putting in actions is just a best practice